# Meaning of "non-trivial three-term arithmetic progressions"

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, arithmetic-progressions, additive-combinatorics

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.0104.pdf) "ON ROTH’S THEOREM ON PROGRESSIONS" by Tom Sanders, the author gives a bound related to "non-trivial three-term arithmetic progressions", but what exactly means "non-trivial" in this context? Or what is an example of a trivial three-term arithmetic progression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Non-trivial" just means "non-constant".  That is, a non-trivial three-term arithmetic progression is a triple of elements of the form $(a,a+b,a+2b)$ where $b\neq 0$ (the $b\neq 0$ condition being what makes it "non-trivial").